# Query and filter by child when child is a list

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to filter and query when my data is a list. In my current database model, I have conversations and then under each UID are the participants of that conversation. I want to be able to look up all conversations a specific user is a part of.

[image: database model]

Im not sure how I would write my code when there is no real "child"

```
let query = Constants.refs.databaseConvo.queryOrdered(byChild: "").queryEqual(toValue: username)
query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        print(childSnapshot)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the limitations of Firebase queries, you will need to create a new collection in your database that keeps track of all of the conversations that a user is a part of. It should be structured something like this:

```
usersConversations {
    userID1 {
        conversationID1: timestamp (or what ever value you would like, I would recommend a timestamp they joined so you can query the latest conversations, etc.)
        conversationID2: timestamp 
        conversationID3: timestamp
    userID2 {
        conversationID1: timestamp
        conversationID2: timestamp
    } ... and so on
}
```

You will need to add and delete to this collection whenever a user joins or leaves a conversation as well as your existing `conversations` collection.

You can then get all of the conversations a user with the uid `userID` is a part of by doing something like this:

```
databaseRef.child("usersConversations").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) (snapshot) in {
    if snapshot.exists() {
         // each snapshot child's key will be a conversationID that they are a part of 

    } else {
         // the user is part of no conversations
    }

}
```